# Closure compiler ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS force method rename?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Is there a way to force Closure compiler in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode to rename/shorten the `pushState()` method, since it is not being used in the context of a History API?

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Moo() {}

Moo.prototype = {
  pushState: function(foo) {
    console.log(foo);
  }
};

var moo = new Moo();
var y = moo.pushState("123");
```

Same with other methods having the same names as native methods on arrays, etc. eg: `myFoo.push()` where `myFoo` is not an array, but an object or instance.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming properties that share a name with any property in an extern file requires the type based optimizations. Recent releases of the command line version of the compiler enable these by default. With the type-based optimizations, properties are not renamed when the compiler is missing type information.

However, your test case is fully renamed with the type-based optimizations.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @use_types_for_optimization true
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/** @constructor */
function Moo() {}

Moo.prototype = {
 pushState: function(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
 }
};

var moo = new Moo();
var y = moo.pushState("123");
```